# How to force QMenuBar to have the same background color as QToolBar

Tags: qt, qt4, stylesheet, qtoolbar, qmenubar

My menu bar is placed inside my toolbar :) And I wan't both of them to have the same background color. In some color themes menubar background is different then in toolbars (lighter). How do I sync them and at the same time maintain current theme colors.

Can I force `QMenuBar` not to draw background ?

I tried to use stylesheets with `background-color:..` but submenus in menu bar lose borders and there is now hover effect.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
QPalette palette = menuBar->palette();
palette.setColor(QPalette::Button,  toolBar->palette().color(QPalette::Window));
menuBar->setPalette(palette);
```

Hope this helps :)